# My Code will work on a Desktop but not my Laptop

Tags: subfig

For whatever reason I keep getting an error when I run this code on my laptop, it says I have an extra  { but when I run this exact code on a different machine it works just fine. when I remove the } on the specified line it says I forgot to add a }. Please help! I just updated my textmaker in the hopes that that would solve the problem but it didnt. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{color}


\sloppy
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\begin{document}

\section{Experimental Setup}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{experimentaldesign.png}
\caption{96-well plate containing A549-HLC3 I cells treated with 25 $\mu$M Rapamycin (RAP), 5 nM Bafilomycin(BAF), and 0.1$\%$ Dimethyl Sulfoxide (DMSO) as VC. Cells were treated with Period I(PI) treatments for 24 hours, cells were then "rinsed" with drug-free media and treated with treatments for period II (see above). Red lines represent wells not included in the analysis, blue lines represent images taken for period I, and red circles represent wells where images where taken for Period II(PII).}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Results}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Cells Treated with Same Drug Input During PI and PII]{{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{AtoA.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Average Punctae per Cell]{{\includegraphics[width=9cm, height = 8cm]{AnalysisPIPII_01.png} }}%
    \caption{\textbf{(a)} side-by-side images taken for PI (left) and PII (right) for VC, RAP, and BAF. VC-R and VC-B represent vehicle control images taken with a Fluorescent Olympus IX83-Inverted Microscope with specific light intensity settings for Rapamycin and Bafilomycin respectively. \textbf{(b)} Average punctae per cell analysis using SparQ pluggin for FIJI(ImageJ). Error bars represent standard deviation ($\pm$SD). }%
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering VC to RAP and BAF]{{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{VCto2.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Average Punctae per Cell]{{\includegraphics[width=9cm, height = 8cm]{AnalysisPIPII_02.png} }}%
    \caption{\textbf{(a)} Cells treated with VC for PI (left) then treated with RAP and BAF for PII (right). \textbf{(b)} Average punctae per cell analysis. Error bars represent standard deviation ($\pm$SD).}%
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering RAP to VC and BAF]{{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{RAPto2.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Average Punctae per Cell]{{\includegraphics[width=9cm, height = 8cm]{AnalysisPIPII_03.png} }}%
    \caption{\textbf{(a)} Cells treated with RAP for PI (left) then treated with VC and BAF for PII (right). \textbf{(b)} Average punctae per cell analysis. Error bars represent standard deviation ($\pm$SD).}%
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering BAF to VC and RAP]{{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{BAFto.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Average Punctae per Cell]{{\includegraphics[width=9cm, height = 8cm]{AnalysisPIPII_04.png} }}%
    \caption{\textbf{(a)} Cells treated with BAF for PI (left) then treated with VC and RAP for PII (right). \textbf{(b)} Average punctae per cell analysis. Error bars represent standard deviation ($\pm$SD).}%
\end{figure}

\section{T-test}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Ttest.png}
\caption{Schematic Diagram for Determining the Correct T-Test to Use.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It would help us alot if you could trim your example down to the smallest file that works on your desktop but not on your laptop.  Also, if you highlight your code and click `{}`, then it will be properly formatted.

Comment: You probably not have the same file on laptop and PC or they have different LaTeX installation. Anyway, an MWE (Minimal Working Example) will help us to see ifit we can compile without error or what is error you received.

Comment: Are you typesetting with latex rather than pdflatex on one of your systems? You don’t say what the error message is.

Comment: I would check for mismatched package versions.  These should all be listed in your log file.  So compare the log files from the two runs, look for the lines reporting the package loading, and compare the version dates and numbers.

Comment: I ran your document on an up to date pdflatex. No problem with `}{` but I got fed up with having to keep going past all the files that you used but did not provide.

Comment: Hi everyone, Thank you so much for your input, I have posted the error I get when I run this code! I tried running it on another laptop and it also failed to compile. The desktop at work runs this code with no issues at all so imnot sure what could be causing it! Thanks again

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I don't have `experimentaldesign.png`.  Please remove that from your example (you can use `example-image-a` instead).  Please don't post an image of the error message text; copy it from your .log file instead.